# NHibernate problem choosing between CreateSql and CreateCriteria

Tags: nhibernate, criteria

I have a very silly doubt in NHibernate. There are two or three entities of which two are related and one is not related to other two entities. I have to fetch some selected columns from these three tables by joining them. Is it a good idea to use session.CreateSql() or we have to use session.CreateCriteria(). I am really confused here as I could not write the Criteria queries here and forced to use CreateSql. Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in general you should avoid writing SQL whenever possible;
one of the advantages of using an ORM is that it's implementation-agnostic.
that means that you don't know (and don't care) what the underlying database is, and you can actually switch DB providers or tweak with the DB structure very easily.
If you write your own SQL statements you run the risk of them not working on other providers, and also you have to maintain them yourself (for example- if you change the name of the underlying column for the Id property from 'Id' to 'Employee_Id', you'd have to change your SQL query, whereas with Criteria no change would be necessary).

Having said that- there's nothing stopping you from writing a Criteria / HQL that pulls data from more than one table. for example (with HQL):

```
select emp.Id, dep.Name, po.Id  
from Employee emp, Department dep, Posts po
where emp.Name like 'snake' //etc...
```

Comment: your suggestion looks good. We have a problem like our web farm doesn't support's ASP.Net Session. Hence lazy loading wont work in our web farm. So obviously we are not enabling Lazy loading for related entities. So all the entities will be loaded whenever the criteria gets executed. so considering this will CreateSql will be a good solution ?

Comment: I don't really see the relation between web-farm and lazy loading; web-farm scenario would influence your caching but not your fetching. could you explain why you've come to the conclusion that you can't enable lazy loading?

Comment: Sorry for relating lazy loadin and web farms. My problem is give below.you fetch a entity and send it to the view. In the view if I try to access the child collection which is lazy loaded will that work ? it wont because session will not be available there.

Comment: @SnakeEyes: you're right. you should transfer your entities to the view completely initialized. I personally use DTOs and fill them at the service level, thus making sure that everything that the view needs is present inside the DTO. concerning lazy / eager loading- see fetching strategies: http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#performance-fetching

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to make queries with NH.

- **HQL**, the classic way, a powerful object oriented query language. Disadvantage: appears in strings in the code (actually: there is no editor support).
- **Criteria**, a classic way to create dynamic queries without string manipulations. Disadvantages: not as powerful as HQL and not as typesafe as its successors.
- **QueryOver**, a successor of Criteria, which has a nicer syntax and is more type safe.
- **LINQ**, now based on HQL, is more integrated then HQL and typesafe and generally a matter of taste.
- **SQL** as a fallback for cases where you need something you can't get the object oriented way.

I would recommend HQL or LINQ for regular queries, QueryOver (resp. Criteria) for dynamic queries and SQL only if there isn't any other way.

To answer your specific problem, which I don't know: If all information you need for the query is available in the object oriented model, you should be able to solve it by the use of **HQL**.